# Synchronising auto-renewable subscriptions in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store

Consider the following scenario:

1. Apple ID A pays for an auto-renewable subscription (in app).
2. App receipt is updated in the current device.
3. Apple ID A closes app.
4. Apple ID logs out from App Store (notice app receipt still remains in app).
5. User (not logged in with any apple ID) launches app.
6. As receipt has not been updated, the app offers him the options to upgrade, downgrade, cross grade. Incorrectly, if he then decides to log in with a different Apple ID B when making the purchase.

Am I missing something? It seems the only solution would be to refresh the receipt always before allowing to make any purchase. But this will ask for the Apple ID password, which is really bothering.

Comment: The app itself doesn't offer upgrade/downgrade options. It will simply offer purchase options for different subscription levels. When the user purchases one of these products they will be prompted by iOS to login. If they login using id B then they will purchase a new subscription. If they log in with id A then they will get an upgrade/downgrade as appropriate based on what they have already purchased (or they will be told that they have already purchased the product if they chose the same level as they were already subscribed to)

Comment: One of my requirements is to make sure to display the current purchase information in-app. Plus, consider this line in Apple docs: "Users can manage their subscriptions in their account settings on the App Store, or within your app’s interface." Am I to understand this is impossible?

Comment: Subscriptions can only be managed using the subscription management in the App Store. They can purchase in your app, and they will upgrade/downgrade as determined by the purchase process,  but they can't cancel, for example, in your app. I think you are worrying about a pretty rare edge case.  If the user switches AppleID then your store display in your app may be wrong, but they will still see the correct subscription price before they commit to subscribe after they log in during the subscription process.